# Smooth Scroll for database fetched link list

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have searched a lot,but couldn't find anything like my problem.All the smooth scroll approach was applied for number of links,that are specified.

My site allows user to add posts on their page.I would like to fetch the title of the posts(to scroll to specific post) and do smooth scroll,when title link is clicked.But the problem is,I don't know the number of posts,they submitted,as database is updated by user post.

So,how can link user to a given post,when corresponding title is clicked?

I have found for specific number of links,which looks like this

**HTML**

```
<a id="up" href="#down">down</a>
<div class="up"></div>

<a id="down" href="#up">up</a>
<div class="down"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.up {
  width:100px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: red;
}

.down {
  width:100px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

**JQuery**

```
$('#up, #down').on('click', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var target= $(this).get(0).id == 'up' ? $('#down') : $('#up');
$('html, body').stop().animate({
   scrollTop: target.offset().top
}, 1000);
});
```

Here is the part for fetching posts and titles.

```
 $sql3="SELECT * FROM news WHERE id='$idx'";
 $query3=mysqli_query($connect_dude,$sql3);
 $num_row3=mysqli_num_rows($query3);
 $posts="";
 $title_to_scroll="";
  if($num_row3>0){
   while($row3=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query3)){
     $title3=$row3["title"];
     $post3=$row3["post"];
     $date3=$row3["date"];

  $title_to_scroll.="<div id='tit'><a href='#'>$title3</a></div>";
  $posts.="<div id=\"news_post\"><div id='top'><b>Posted on  </b>$date3<h2>$title3<hr id='hrx'></h2></div><br><br><div id='post'>$post3</div></div> ";
}
```

Then I just print that in HTML part

Comment: We would need to see the code for the page that is generating the posts.

Comment: I just fetch post from databse using php and Mysql.So,is there any need to see that code in this example

Comment: there is an absolute need to see how you are creating your html elements

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/

Comment: @Vector Please have a look @ Updated question

Comment: you've not given anyone any indication of properties that can be used to associate user to post. Can use `data-` attributes to place applicable data on post elements and links. Also, element ID's must be unique by definition